# Distinguishing file downloads from web-page requests at the network layer

Tags: c++, networking, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I'm using a packet sniffer on Windows.  How do you tell the difference between a packet that is downloading a file and a packet that is loading a website or just navigating a website?  I realise that http is not a packet and it's on top of a TCP packet but how would I do this?  I'm new and certainly confused!  I'm using C++ and Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Get a book on tcp/ip and read. You got too many misconception.

Comment: perhaps being that you find that I have misconceptions it would be nice if you explained what really happens.  I've already said I was confused, need you point it out again!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the 'file download' is a HTTP file download, not a SMB or FTP one (that is too easy of a question): the HTTP response of a file download *may* contain a [`content-disposition`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) header.

Comment: Thank you, very informative! So I could possibly filter by type of file?

Comment: If the content-disposition contains a `filename` tag then you could use some heuristics based on the file extension. You also have the `content-type` header which would indicate certain file types (eg. `image/jpeg`. However, neither is truly reliable so it depends what is the end goal.

Comment: My goal is to drop packets by content type.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference because they are exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html/#ChIntroWhatIs) to analyse network traffic, and can apply [protocol filters](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/) to view traffic by protocols.

However, protocol filters would not filter if *data* is a file or a page (as Seth mentioned they are the same thing)

Comment: Thank you.  Thats what I was afraid of.